# Sign choice for line element while finding potential due to point charge

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, conventions, integration

The canonical derivation for the $1/r$ potential due to a point charge is as follows:

> We consider an electric field of the form $$\mathbf{E}=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}},$$ and integrate along a straight path from $r'=\infty$ to $r'=r$: $$V_\infty(r)=-\int_\infty^r\mathbf{E}(r')\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}'=-\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(-\frac{1}{r'}\right)^R_\infty=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}.$$

However, if we're integrating along a path from positive infinity to $r$ along the $x$ axis (I switch to cartesian coordinates for simplicity), we should have $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}'=-\mathrm{d}x'\hat{\mathbf{x}}$. The electric field, however, would, for a positive charge, be pointing along the positive $x$ direction, giving negative $\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}'$. This contradicts the canonical derivation, and forces you to pick up an extra minus sign. However, that seems conceptually incorrect: a positive potential is physically reasonable.

Why don't we pick up a minus sign due to the electric field and integration element pointing in opposite directions? Every single source I've checked out seems to gloss over this, from high school physics to Griffiths.

Comment: This is not the appropriate place for checking your sign errors. This question might be closed as a "check-my-work" question.  But, that being said, did you remember that the electric field is the *negative* gradient of the electric potential? Could that be the source of your sign error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canonical or not, I find the approach you give a bit convoluted. As I see it, the potential, $V(R)$ due to point charge $Q$ at displacement $\mathbf R$ from $Q$ is the amount of work per unit test charge that is done by $Q$'s field on a test charge $q$ as  $q$ goes from $\mathbf R$ to infinity. It's easiest to consider $q$ going radially out wrt $Q$. So

$$V(R)=\frac 1q \int_R^\infty \frac {Qq\ \mathbf {\hat {r}}}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}\cdot \mathbf{\hat {r}} dr=\frac Q{4\pi\epsilon_0 R}$$

This is the quantity of work per unit test charge that $Q$'s field  could do on $q$ when $q$ was at $\mathbf R$ from $Q$, but can no longer do when $q$ is at infinity. It is therefore the loss in potential energy of the test charge, per unit  test charge, as it goes from $\mathbf R$ to infinity, that is the fall in potential in going from $\mathbf R$ to infinity. If, for convenience, we take the potential to be zero at infinity, the potential at $R$ from Q must be $Q/4\pi\epsilon_0 R$.

Generally, if the component of field strength in the $\mathbf{\hat z}$ direction is $E_z \mathbf{\hat z}$, for a displacement $\mathbf {\hat z} dz$ the change in potential, $dV$ is $-E_z \mathbf{\hat z}\cdot\mathbf {\hat z} dz$, so we have
$$E_z=-\frac{\partial V}{\partial z}.$$